# How to access the values of web part properties in the layout?

Tags: kentico

In the Kentico Documentation I only found the info as below...

[image]

Is there any way to access the properties value in the layout as show below? I tried to use macro but it didn't work.

[image]

I just want to display the properties value in my custom layout. Any methods other than access through the code? I'm using portal engine, I have no idea how to access the code behind...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout is `ASCX`, so you won't be able to use macros as per your example.

- If you just need the value, you can use the `GetValue` method. There's also `GetStringValue`, if the type of your property is a `string`

```cs
    <% GetStringValue("MyPropertiesValue1", string.Empty); %>
```

- If you need to *render* the value, you will need to call `Page.DataBind()` and use a data binding expression. Your layout would look something like this:

```cs
    <%# GetStringValue("MyPropertiesValue1", string.Empty) %>
    <%# GetStringValue("MyPropertiesValue2", string.Empty) %>

    <script runat="server">
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.DataBind();
        }
    </script>
```

None if this is really elegant, so you might want to reconsider your approach.

Comment: Not really understand why the function need to pass in `string.Empty` as a parameter, since I'm getting value not setting any value.

Comment: How to put it correctly if I want to sub the value into the html tag properties? 
Like 
`<h1 class="<% GetStringValue("MyPropertiesValue1", string.Empty) %>"></h1>`

Comment: The `string.Empty` parameter is the default value. So, if the value of `MyPropertiesValue1` is `null`, `GetStringValue` will return `string.Empty`.

Comment: Regarding your `h1` tag - make sure you add the `#` to make it a data binding expression. `<h1 class="<%#GetStringValue("MyPropertiesValue1", string.Empty) %>">Title</h1>`

Comment: THX! @Kristian Bortnik